# Sort nested list based on name and datetime object

Tags: python

I have a nested string format like

```
lis = [
    ["val1", "2018-06-29 08:15:27"], 
    ["val2", "2018-06-29 08:15:27"], 
    ["val2", "2019-06-29 08:15:27"]
    ]
```

I want to sort based on "name" (`index[0]`), and then if "name" is the same, it should sort based on the date (`index[1]`).

Code that I have tried:

```
    sorted(list, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

Comment: And is there a problem ? You have o datetime object, just strings of it

Comment: Why not just `lis.sort()`?

Comment: It would be nice to see some expected output, because from the `-x[1]` my hunch is that @Nitesh is trying to sort reverse on the datetimes. If so, that's not possible in a one-liner using `key`; check sorting's [Operator Module Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html). You would be sorting first by "value" then by "datetime".

Comment: @Algebra8 It's easily possible in a one-liner using `key`.

Comment: Also, it will sort the entire list again, won't maintain the order of "name", e.g. you won't get `["val1", "2018"], ["val2", "2019"], ["val2", "2018"]` in this example, since it will sort the entire list again based on the datetime.

Comment: I see, `sorted(z, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))` actually works if you're using `int`s. I think we were looking at two different things.

Comment: @Algebra8 Yeah, that's not what I'm talking about. I mean one that works for strings.

Comment: @Algebra8 Let me clarify. *Most* of your comment was wrong. The one thing you got right is that it sorts twice. I allowed myself to disregard that, as it's a minor issue if any, and since I consider the probably implied "that makes it slow" as wrong (two sorts by one simple criterion each can even be *faster* than one sort by the combination of the two criteria).

Answer (score 0):

You should only sort the integer number after the val string which is int(x[3:]). For the date sort, you should convert it to datetime. Following snippet should sort as you want.

```
    sorted(lis,key=lambda x: (int(x[0][3:]),datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Comment: what is int(x[0][3:]) relates to

Comment: x[0] gives you following string "val123" to get the integer part i take x[0][3:] which is "123". I assume all the keys are starting with the val. However, if you have different strings then you should not cast into integer and not take [3:]

Comment: This is a convoluted way of doing `sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(0, 1))`, you can check the outputs, they are the same. Also, you don't need to convert to datetime - str checks would be equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Just convert the date string to datetime as follows, and use sorted. The sorted function
will automatically sort by the first item in sublist and then break ties by the second:

```
import datetime
sorted([[x[0],datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] for x in lis])
```

Note that when sorting strings, you should expect a lexicographic order.

Answer (score -3):

You can try ternary operator for such case:

```
sorted(lis, key = lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == x[1] else x[0])
```